# How to access Rails instance variable from Vue.js component?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am trying to access rails instance variable from Vue component. I am not sure whether it's possible or not. My controller code looks like this

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @role = @current_user.role # I need to access this instance variable in Vue component.
  end
end
```

And my Vue component looks like this

```
<template>
  <v-container class="my-1 py-0">
    <v-card>
      <a v-bind:href="`/score_cards/new?tournament_match_id=${match.DT_RowId}`">Upload Score Card</a> # I want to display this link only when @role == 'admin'
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

So I only want to display `Upload Score Card` link if `@role == 'admin'`. So how can I achieve this is Vue.js ? How can I access `@role` instance variable in Vue ?

Answer (score -1):

You can pass Rails variables to Javascript, but you need to embed them in the HTML page first, and your JS code reads them from the HTML.

Insert your variables into the HTML like this.

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "variables", data: { 
  first_variable: @variable_1,
  second_variable: @variable_2 
} do %>
<% end %>
```

This will output a `div` in the generated webpage like this.

```html
<div class="variables" data-first-variable="[VALUE]" data-second-variable="[VALUE]">
```

You then read them into your JS like this.

```js
$('.variables').data('firstVariable')
```

(This is JQuery notation, as you'll see, but I'm sure you can do something similar in Vue.)